Gazebo dynamically modify parameters in plugin
I am looking for a way to dynamically change the variables that has been predefined in a robot model sdf file. In particular, I would like to tune the parameters of the velocity (lee) controller of the MultiCopterVelocity controller like the velocityGains. I want to first enquire what is possible in Gazebo from the start and if there is any functionality that I'm looking for that exist but I'm simple not aware of.
I know that in some simulators or gaming engines it is possible to expose these variables and change them dynamically on the fly, but I'm not sure if such a functionality exists in Gazebo (not classic). Would it require me to integrate that into the multicopter control plugin to take input of gazebo topics, or is there another way that I can try, like with the python interface or such?
Thanks!
